# Real Time API using JSON

Tags: json, sockets, protocols, application-layer, realtime-api

I wish to send commands on a web socket to the backend. I was thinking my protocol should look like this:

Send: `{cmd: "login", data: {user:"Me",id:99}}` Reply: `{cmd: "login", data: "OK"}`

Send: `{cmd: "join sensors", data: {group:1}}` Reply: `{cmd: "join sensors", data: "OK"}`

Send: `{cmd: "join actuators", data: {group:1}}` Reply: `{cmd: "join actuators", data: "NOK"}`

I will always wait for a response before issuing a new request.

I can also receive events from the BE:

`{evt:"sensor update", data: {id:1,value;20}}`

Is my design sensible? Is there a more standardised approach?

Comment: you can also try to send JSON according to your data types (already defined), such as { data: { type: "login", user: "Me", id: 99 } }  and as reply, only the status code is fine.